# Exceeding Instagram API request limit

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How can I possibly exceed the Instagram API limit of 500 requests per hour if I have code in place that caches every 15 seconds (240 requests per hour)?

UPDATE: We ended up creating a new client, generating a new access token and using that in in our app. So far so good. Our code is making 1 call per minute, caching it and displaying the cached data for most visitors. The only thing I can think of is maybe something else was using our access token - leaking our bank of requests. I wish Instagram kept a log or something so we could see if requests were coming from an unauthorized source.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: You are asking how you can code an illegal program?

Comment: Nothing illegal here. My code simply reduces the number of API calls by storing and using the previously successful call data. Especially useful since Instagram seems to go down an awful lot these days.

Answer (score 0):

which API is it?

Instagram POST APIs have different limits (30/hr in sandbox and 60/hr in live mode):

```
/media/media-id/likes
/media/media-id/comments
/users/user-id/relationships
```

combined all API calls have 5000/hour.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: Thanks. We're just making this call to get our recent posts. https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Comment: are you in sandbox or live mode ?

Comment: Sandbox. We submitted for review, but were not approved for live. We're not doing anything special - just displaying our last two posts on our website.

Comment: ok, once you are live you should be able to go up to 5000/hr, I make request 1 a second for some applications and it works, that's 3600 calls/hour.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure we'll get approved to go live, so we may be stuck with 500 per hour. Which isn't bad, we were making calls every 15 seconds which equals 240 calls per hour, but for some reason we were hitting 1500+ which I can't figure out.

Comment: if you just want basic permission, which is what u just need, it should be easy to get approved.

Comment: only the last 3 are valid, choose this "My app allows people to login with Instagram and share their own content" and request only `basic`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of trying that. Seemed like that one use case was exactly what we were doing. Just submitted our app. Fingers crossed.